# How to work out the integral $\int e^x·\sqrt{1+e^x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

$\int e^x·\sqrt{1+e^x}\,dx$

Can someone explain to me how to work this integral out?
I tried integration by parts, however, that does not give a clear answer.
I got a hint from our professor that we should use substitution, but if I substitute "$ 1+e^x$" for example, I still can't calculate it by integration by parts...

Comment: let $1+e^x=u$. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Substitute $1+e^{ x }=u$ then $du={ e }^{ x }dx$

$$\\ \\ \int  e^{ x }\sqrt { 1+e^{ x } } \,dx=\int  \sqrt { u } \,du=\frac { 2u\sqrt { u }  }{ 3 } +C=\\ =\frac { 2 }{ 3 } { \left( { e }^{ x }+1 \right)  }^{ \frac { 3 }{ 2 }  }+C$$

Comment: It's $\frac23(1+e^x)^\frac32+C$ not $\frac32(e^x)^\frac32+C$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire,it was a typo,thank you

Comment: Note also the inversion of $\frac32$ :)

Comment: today is not my day (

Comment: You forgot a : in your smily LOL

Answer (score 2):

Do the substitution $1+e^x=t$ and $e^x\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm dt$.